# Is it expected that during self-play reinforcement learning that player 1 or player 2 wins the majority of games?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

I'm testing various learning rates and neural network configurations. I'm testing over 10000 games, with the first 2000 having random starting moves and general randomness throughout of about 20%, i.e. 20% of moves are random.

In all configurations, I initiate the weights to random values.

What I've found is that in all configurations, Player 1 will win the majority of games, or Player 2 will. There's no 50/50 split.

Is this expected or normal? I am training on the Connect Four game.

Comment: This is weird, how big are the majorities? I would also decrease your epsilon (probability of random move) as training progresses. Do you test with an epsilon?

Comment: @jaden What are "the majorities", I'm not familiar with this term. I do reduce the randomness over time, it starts at something like 50% and drops to 10% after the first 10% of moves. 20% was way off.

Comment: By majorities i mean by how much does player 1 beat player 2 (eg 90%) and vice versa.

Comment: It's hard to tell, it's a win or lose, there's no score or anything.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in regards to what you said about there is no 50/50 split. What is the split? Like 90/10?

Comment: @Jaden, yeah it's like 90/10 but starts to go up the more i increase the amount of random moves, but only because those moves ending randomly are getting wins for the other player. It's  also sometimes player 1 or sometimes player 2, I believe related to what the random weights maybe lean to at the start.

Comment: What Reinforcement Learning algorithm are you using? Something like Q-learning, or Policy Gradients? Can you also elaborate on how the "self-play" is set up? Does each player have a Network of their own (and if so, are they using same or different configs), or are they both using and learning parameters for the same network at the same time? I realise this request for more info is a bit late, hopefully you're still around :)

Comment: @dennis_soemers I am always around. It was using backward propagation. They were using the same network. The game was Connect4 so I figured they didn't need their own networks as the state given is always the same, just swapped out the "player" vs "opponent" values in the input.

Answer (score -2):

From [wikipedia article on  Connect Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four):

> Connect Four is a solved game. The first player can always win by
>   playing the right moves.

It's pretty reasonable that even without training 1st player win more often by small margin.
With some training  1st player should mostly win.